# How to merge multiple arrays in a single array variable with order of one object in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular8

In my application If i use multiple product(arrays - product1,product2,product3...] I am not able to add selected product details in my cart.It is not working properly.If i select one product three products is adding So this is wrong.It is working only if i use single array like product1.I think p_id is issue.So I do not know how to resolve this issue.Anyone can find the solution?

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-selvam-ecommerce-task-g95orn?file=src/app/pages/products/products.pages.ts

product.pages.ts:

ngOnInit(){

```
  this.ref();
      this.selectedProducts=[...this.product1,...this.product2,...this.product3];
  }
  ref(){
    this.cartflag = false;
    setTimeout( () => {
        this.cartflag = true;
    }, 10 )
  }

  productShow(prd){ 
        this.selectedProducts=this[prd];  
  }
```

Comment: If product is an object, the `...` isn't likely what you want

Comment: @AluanHaddad: Click Add to cart button then click cart icon then see what is happening